# How to run a function on all members of a list using linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Objects that I am receiving performing web service call.

```
List<ProcessInstances> list = processService.GetProcessInstances(id);
```

I want to call a function on each member of the list. I could use a For loop but I want to use a linq query since I will be doing this (reading from the web service) quite a few times in my code. So far I have,

```
list.Select(obj => GetProcessedParameters(obj.Id));

//GetProcessedParameters(int id) does some lookup and validation based on the id.
```

But that gives me an error saying the type is not recognized. Why is it giving me an error? How would I accomplish this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Select` is looking for you to return a value inside the lambda.

Try:

```
list.ForEach(obj => GetProcessedParameters(obj.Id));
```

Using [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in this way is actually nominally slower than writing out a `For` loop, but much more readable.

Comment: [`ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z(v=vs.110).aspx) is just a method of `List<T>` and not a part of LINQ.

Comment: Thanks! So Select would return the members of the list that are equal to GetProcessedParameters(obj.Id)? GetProcesesParameters(obj.Id) would then have to have a return type the same as obj?

Comment: @ArunavDev, `Select` would return a list of whatever `GetProcessedParameters` returned, but it would have to return something.

Comment: @ArunavDev: `select` is how you turn a list of one kind of thing into a list of something else via a function or expression. Very handy.

Comment: Well said @david.pfx.  If you wanted to RESTRICT the values returned you would use a `Where` like, `.Where(obj => GetProcessParameters().Contains(obj))`  I'm speculating that `GetProcessedParameters()` returns a list of valid obj's.